# Storyboard design - how to show standard hairline?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I'd like to design screen similar to standard mail client.
They separate fields (recipients, subject) with tiny hairline (gray). Same as TableView cell separators.

How do I show such line myself? I tried to put UIView 1pt high with background. It works, but 1pt is thicker (2px) and I don't know what color it supposed to be.

Any better alternatives?

**NOTE:**

I was thinking about UITableView with static cells, but it will make layout overly complex. I have different size blocks and UITextView which will be scrollable inside table cell? I also need to hide/show blocks depends on situation which means table cells will have to show/hide. I also don't need separators between each block. Currently UI works very elegant with Storyboard constraints.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [`UITableView` with static cells](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/05/07/static-table-views-with-storyboards.html) and borderless `UITextField`s.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but it will make layout overly complex. I have different size blocks and UITextView which will be scrollable inside table cell? I also need to hide/show blocks depends on situation which means table cells will have to show/hide. I also don't need separators between each block. Currently UI works very elegant with Storyboard constraints.

Comment: You should mention it in your question.

Comment: I'd definitely go with the tableviews too. Takes care of much of the work for you..

Comment: BTW. You can use tableHeaderView and tableFooterView for your complex UI.

Comment: Do you think they use TableView for standard email client?